# Add pages to a Word Document from Access VBA?

Tags: templates, ms-access, vba, ms-word, bookmarks

I have a .dot Word template, and I loop through the bookmarks to fill the Document.

I'm filling the template for each RecordSet's Row, but I'm creating a new/separated Word Document.

Can I Add Pages to the document or merge individual documents to open a single Word document with all pages that I need?

This is an schema of my code

```
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()

If Not rst.EOF Then
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rst.EOF()

        Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(DOC_PATH & DOC_NAME, , True)
        For Each bm In doc.Bookmarks
        ' Fill Bookmarks
        Next bm
        appWord.Documents.Open filename:=DOC_PATH & DOC_NAME
    Loop 
End If
rst.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using InsertFile to append all the documents to the first one you open?  You could also insert page breaks if you want (not shown here)

```
Dim W As New Word.Application
W.Visible = True
Dim D As Document: Set D = W.Documents.Add
Dim R As Word.Range: Set R = D.Range
R.InsertFile "c:\somefile.doc"
```